# can't update sql table when submitting form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site that has forms to insert, delete and update records for a database.

I have no problem inserting and deleting records, but I can't seem to put the UPDATE working. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<form class="about-form" action="" method="POST">
    <p class="title">About</p>
    <textarea class="textarea" name="text" rows="8" cols="80" disabled><?php echo $about->content_text; ?></textarea><br>
    <input class="edit-button" type="button" name="edit" value="Edit">
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" class="save-button">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
//get a content text from the database
$about = $db->get_single_row("SELECT * FROM content WHERE content_id='2'");
if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $aboutText = $_POST['text'];
    $db->query("UPDATE content SET content_text='$aboutText' WHERE content_id='2'");
}
```

The error message I get is this:
**"Notice: Undefined index: text"**

**UPDATE:**
I have two buttons, one to edit (that removes the disabled) and one to save(puts back disabled and submits).
I managed to do the UPDATE after removing the javascript of the button "save". 
Managed to UPDATE after removing javascript for the save button. How can i put the disabled or readonly after submitting the form?

Comment: Did you try to `echo` the UPDATE query before launch it and had paste it in phpmyadmin for see what is happenning with this?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do when using the [low-level SQL server driver](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using. **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I'll read about it. This site is made for school purpose, i know security is still very very low

Answer (score 2):

Your element named "text" is disabled, so will not post on submission.  I suspect the problem you're having is that $_POST['text'] is blank, but you weren't clear what error (if any) you were seeing.

Comment: I have two buttons, one to "Edit" that removes the disabled. Still, i tried without the disabled and still can't make the update. Posted the error in reply of my post.

Comment: So, your receiving script doesn't seem to be getting the post.  I would try to use $_REQUEST['text'] to see if perhaps it's actually a GET.  Is what you're showing all of the relevant code?  The other thing I would try is using a different name for your element.  Say, name='about'.  try to output $_POST as well to see what's there:  print_r($_POST);  A few debugging shots in the dark.  Without the full code, it's hard to give a precise answer.

Answer (score 2):

disabled input will not submit data.

Use the readonly attribute:

```
 <textarea class="textarea" name="text" rows="8" cols="80" readonly >
```

Comment: didn't know that existed. Thank you, but still doesn't work

Comment: just try print_r($_POST);

Answer (score 1):

Why did you put the disabled attribute to the text area ?

### Remove 'disabled attribute' and try it.

If that does not work.
It seems like your textarea input field is not linked with the form.
so add a name attribute to the form then add a form attribute to the textarea with value to name of the form.

```
<form class="about-form" action="" method="POST" name="myform">
  <p class="title">About</p>
  <textarea class="textarea" name="text" rows="8" cols="80" form="myform" disabled><?php echo $about->content_text; ?></textarea><br>
  <input class="edit-button" type="button" name="edit" value="Edit">
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" class="save-button">
</form>
```

---

so please put the error message u got after trying.

Comment: I edited the question with the error message. It's not the disabled option because i have an edit button to remove the disabled

Comment: Did you try assign a name to the form and add a form attribute to the textarea field ?

Comment: already fixed it. The problem was the save button i had that defined again the disabled before submitting the query

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the replies.

I Managed to fix it by substituting disabled for readonly. But the main problem was the "save" button witch was putting back the disabled attribute before submitting the query